# How to add a Dataset parameter into the Url in rdlc reporting

Tags: rdlc

Hi I am new to rdlc reporting and in my project I have to pass Latitude and Longitude into the URL which is defined for a textbox. So what I was using is `https://www.google.com.my/maps/place//Fields!TRIPSTARTLATITUDE.Value,Fields!TRIPSTARTLONGITUDE.Value,15z?hl=en`

but by using the above code it is not going to the exact position **I also want to add a marker in that particular position**. I think the reason is because it is not decoding the value of the parameter.So give me some suggestion on how to pass the dataset parameter into the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the lat and long being passed into the report (either via parameters or your dataset) then you can use some code on the url to assemble it with the values.

Eg:

```
="https://www.google.com.my/maps/place//" & Fields!TRIPSTARTLATITUDE.Value & "," & Fields!TRIPSTARTLONGITUDE.Value & ",15z?hl=en"
```

Comment: it worked just had to change place// to place/ thank you so much